# MacOS Contacts App — How can I tell to which address book an entry belongs?

Tags: macos, contacts.app

I have two entries that appear identical to each other. One is in the `iCloud` address book. The other is `On My Mac`.

I have opened up both entries, but I can't tell which is which.

Is there a way to discern this?

### Note

I have been opening both entries and editing one to see which is which. I'm hoping for a better solution than this.

#### Show Groups

The `Show Groups` option displays a list of groups on the left. This isn't what I am looking for. Ideally, if opening up a contacts card will show you a list of groups to which that card belongs.

Comment: Make a simple change to one of them and see where the change propagates to.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, that's what I've been doing. I'm looking for a visual indication built into the app itself. Thanks. Updating the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is obvious, but in the Contacts App, Click on View->Show Groups.  Then you can select the contact in either group?

Comment: Yes, I already have `Show Groups` on. That just turns on the groups column on the left.